I am trying to use Java Beads library sound
I am using Windows 10 and Eclipse IDE.
I have installed the Beads library for the IDE I am using.
This is the error.
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface SourceDataLine supporting     format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
at java.desktop/com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer.getLine(PortMixer.java:125)
at net.beadsproject.beads.core.io.JavaSoundAudioIO.create(Unknown Source)
at net.beadsproject.beads.core.io.JavaSoundAudioIO$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

I am trying to generate a sine wave audio using a script.
The script I wrote tells me that it has the audio device and displays it's name.
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import net.beadsproject.beads.core.AudioContext;
import net.beadsproject.beads.core.io.JavaSoundAudioIO;
import net.beadsproject.beads.data.Buffer;
import net.beadsproject.beads.ugens.WavePlayer;

public class AudioDevice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //This selects the audio device.
        JavaSoundAudioIO jsaio = new JavaSoundAudioIO();
        jsaio.selectMixer(0);
        //Creates an audio context.
        AudioContext ac = new AudioContext(jsaio);
        //Shows the format info such as sample rate and encoding.
        ac.postAudioFormatInfo();
        //Creates a sine generator for the audio device.
        WavePlayer wp = new WavePlayer(ac, 440.0f, Buffer.SINE);
        //The input sine wave goes into the output device which is the one I have selected.
        ac.out.addInput(wp);
        //Starts the audio. This is where it fails.
        ac.start();
        

    }

}


Does it work without selecting the audio device? Without the first 2 lines of code and using the default constructor of AudioContext it becomes the literal example of how to use beads

I just found out how to get it running by doing some testing.
